# How to avoid duplicating comments when compiling SCSS files with Compass?

Tags: magento, sass, compass-sass

I'm using Magento 1.9 and SCSS/Compass. Whenever I change a file, the outputted CSS file is correctly changed but comments (that all Magento files have) at the top of file are duplicated for some reason. For example I made one change to a file and then the outputted CSS file had the comments duplicated 6 times. It seems every time I add or edit something, the comments are continuously being duplicated. 
This becomes annoying when having to check the CSS files (having to scroll through this).

Is there a way to address this with SCSS/Compass? I'm using Compass with PHP Storm (7.1.3)

Answer (score 0):

With the given information I see 2 options.

- It's most likely settings related. In your configuration file ( config.rb if you're using one ) what you could try is commenting some of the options in that file and recompile the scss files to see if it's a setting affecting your compiled code.
- Please double check that your comments are not 2 times declared in your .scss files.

Let me know if that helps in any way.